# Is the sizeof union always the sizeof the largest datatype inside it?

Tags: c

I try a simple code to see the size of the union I create and it say the size is 52 instead 50. I try with another string of the same size and it give 50 like normal. Where does the extra 2 byte coming from?

Here the code

```
union Name
{
    int y;
    float x;
    char name[50];
}name;

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
char name2[50];
printf("%d",sizeof(name));
printf("\n%d",sizeof(name2));
return 0;
}
```

The result is 52 and 50.

Comment: Don't use `"%d"` for `sizeof`'s value. Use `"%zu"`.

Comment: The size of a union is the size of its largest member, *rounded up* to the *alignment* of its most alignment-restricted member.

Comment: @TomKarzes Usually true in practice, although the standard places no upper bound; and probably there are implementation-specific extensions to not do the rounding up

Answer (score 3):

Per ISO 9899:201x (C11) draft, (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **S6.7.2.1**:
>
> paragraph 16: The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. [...]
>
> paragraph 17: There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

**[Edit: to use a more recent draft, per comment by @M.M]**

Answer (score 2):

Alignment. If you tried to create an array of these unions, and they only had a `sizeof` of 50, the `x` and `y` members wouldn't be efficiently aligned. The size is padded to a multiple of 4 to satisfy alignment constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation can be summed up in -

> The size of an object of a union type is the amount of storage necessary to
>   represent the largest component of that type, **plus any padding**
>   that may be needed at the end to **raise the length upto an alignment
>   boundary**.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessarily 52. **The extra 2 bytes doesn't store data. It's padding space.**

If you change `float y` to `double y`, you'll even see 56 :)

Some data types require alignment for whatever reasons. In your case, `float y` requires to be aligned to 4 bytes. If sizeof the union is only 50, and you create `name n[2]`, then `n[1].y` isn't well aligned. So the sizeof union is padded up to 52 (4*13) for alignment concerns.